# What are parameterized queries explained in plain English?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, parameterized-query

Can anybody explain me in plain English what parametrized queries are and how to implement it in PHP for a MySQL database to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: The answers to [the question, that this one is a suspected duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php), does not explain what parameterized queries are.

Comment: What part of your question is more important to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [prepared statements and stored procedures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) section of the PHP manual, whilst it relates specifically to PDO, covers this well when it says:

> They can be thought of as a kind of
>   compiled template for the SQL that an
>   application wants to run, that can be
>   customized using variable parameters.
>   Prepared statements offer two major
>   benefits:
>
> - The query only needs to be parsed (or
>     prepared) once, but can be executed
>     multiple times with the same or
>     different parameters. When the query
>     is prepared, the database will
>     analyze, compile and optimize it's
>     plan for executing the query. For
>     complex queries this process can take
>     up enough time that it will noticeably
>     slow down an application if there is a
>     need to repeat the same query many
>     times with different parameters. By
>     using a prepared statement the
>     application avoids repeating the
>     analyze/compile/optimize cycle. This
>     means that prepared statements use
>     fewer resources and thus run faster.
> - The parameters to prepared statements
>     don't need to be quoted; the driver
>     automatically handles this. If an
>     application exclusively uses prepared
>     statements, the developer can be sure
>     that no SQL injection will occur
>     (however, if other portions of the
>     query are being built up with
>     unescaped input, SQL injection is
>     still possible).

If you're after specific example of how to use them, the above linked page also includes code samples.